# Is there a maximum limit for SSRS subscription parameters?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2014

We have a SSRS report which has about 12 parameters. It works fine in native webpage mode. We can input/select values for the parameters, and run report successfully. However, when user setup report subscription, there are only four parameters were populated with values, the others are blank.
Is there a maximum limit settings in report server, to control how many parameter can be used in subscription?

Answer (score 0):

I just created a report with 20 text parameters and a subscription with hard-coded values for all 20 and it ran perfectly. In terms of production-quality reports, I have some that have up to 25 parameters, although I've never run them via a subscription.

In terms of what your user experienced, I would recommend checking your parameter default values to see if they allow blanks or default to blanks. If the parameters are internal and they allow or default to null or blank and are internal, then they will yield blanks in the subscription.

If your parameters are internal, then the user cannot specify a value via a subscription. If the parameter is hidden, then I believe a default value is necessary and the user will be prompted with an option to change the default value.

After a quick google search, I couldn't find an answer to your question. I suspect there is more of a practical limit to the number of parameters you can use than there is a hard limit.

See [this article on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337234.aspx) for more information on internal versus hidden parameters. Perhaps this can be helpful for you in terms of minimizing parameters that are configurable.